# XSD for soap result not working

Tags: xml, soap, xsd

I want to check a soap response against a xsd. 
Here is the xml soap response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetHTMLResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
            <GetHTMLResult>
                Test
            </GetHTMLResult>
        </GetHTMLResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here is my XSD:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
<xs:element name="GetHTMLResponse">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element  name="GetHTMLResult" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
         </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I get this error: 
**Cvc-elt.1: Cannot Find The Declaration Of Element 'soap:Envelope'**.

Why is this happening?

Comment: If you look closely, you'll notice that your XSD files doesn't describe what the SOAP service is sending back as a response.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the SOAP response against the following XSD file.  I added elements for the outer `<soap:Envelope>` and `<soap:Body>` tags which are present in the SOAP response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.example.org"
xmlns:tns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">

<xs:element name="Envelope" type="tns:envType">
  <xs:complexType name="envType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Body" type="tns:bodyType">
        <xs:complexType name="bodyType">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="GetHTMLResponse">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="GetHTMLResult" minOccurs="0"
                              maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                  </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution on: http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html, getting following error: S4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute 'form' Cannot Appear In Element 'element'.

Comment: Remove the `form` attributes and try again, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: Now I got following error: S4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute 'name' Cannot Appear In Element 'complexType'.