# Create XSD for SOAP Response

Tags: xml, validation, soap, xsd

I want to create a XSD for validating a SOAP response(XML). However, I am facing the error - "Cannot Find The Declaration Of Element 'soap:Envelope'". I tried adding the soap:Envelope element to XSD and I get this error - "'soap:Envelope' Is Not A Valid Value For 'NCName'".

My XML is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetValidOrdersBySalesOppAndLocationResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
         <GetValidOrdersBySalesOppAndLocationResult>
            <Order>
               <ASV__c>0</ASV__c>
               <Date_Submitted__c>2015-08-25T11:02:07</Date_Submitted__c>
               <Order_Id>1365577</Order_Id>
               <End_Date__c>0001-01-01T00:00:00</End_Date__c>
               <Entitlement_Length__c>0</Entitlement_Length__c>
            </Order>
            <Order>
               <ASV__c>0</ASV__c>
               <Date_Submitted__c>2015-08-24T23:11:19.75</Date_Submitted__c>
               <Order_Id>1365580</Order_Id>
               <End_Date__c>0001-01-01T00:00:00</End_Date__c>
               <Entitlement_Length__c>0</Entitlement_Length__c>
            </Order>
            <Order>
               <ASV__c>0</ASV__c>
               <Date_Submitted__c>2015-08-25T11:19:10</Date_Submitted__c>
               <Order_Id>1365581</Order_Id>
               <End_Date__c>0001-01-01T00:00:00</End_Date__c>
               <Entitlement_Length__c>0</Entitlement_Length__c>
            </Order>
         </GetValidOrdersBySalesOppAndLocationResult>
      </GetValidOrdersBySalesOppAndLocationResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My XSD is below:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.webserviceX.NET" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="GetValidOrdersBySalesOppAndLocationResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="GetValidOrdersBySalesOppAndLocationResult">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Order" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="ASV__c"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:dateTime" name="Date_Submitted__c"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:int" name="Order_Id"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:dateTime" name="End_Date__c"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="Entitlement_Length__c"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I used the online XSD generator - http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html and Validator - http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html.

I also checked out other stackoverflow questions. There is an exact question similar to mine, however it does not have an working solution which can be found here - [XSD for soap result not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839149/xsd-for-soap-result-not-working). I could not comment asking for an update from OP due to my low points. Please help.

UPDATE:
Adding an import works!

Working code(Added the second line):

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.webserviceX.NET"     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/> //Added import
  <xs:element name="GetValidOrdersBySalesOppAndLocationResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="GetValidOrdersBySalesOppAndLocationResult">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Order" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="ASV__c"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:dateTime" name="Date_Submitted__c"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:int" name="Order_Id"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:dateTime" name="End_Date__c"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="Entitlement_Length__c"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: did you sanitize check this if it really works? 

I've tried changing the "GetValidOrdersBySalesOppAndLocationResponse" from your xml to "GetValidAAAAAAAAOrdersBySalesOppAndLocationResponse" and it still validates it. 

The validation should fail since GetValidAAAAAAAAOrdersBySalesOppAndLocationResponse was not declared in .XSD

Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into using the original XSD for SOAP envelopes and use that. Then extend with `xs:import` into your own XSD the necessary datatypes that you want to validate. Using the SOAP XSD will allow you to validate any SOAP request. To validate your own types, just add your own for the generic part.

A better approach is usually to only validate the custom part, as any SOAP compliant service server or client will throw an error if the envelope is not valid SOAP. It also saves you time if you just focus on that part.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Abel. Using "xs:import" worked. My requirement is kinda rigid, I have a in house website at work which basically validates the response returned by a SOAP web service. The website needs an XSD as input to validate the full SOAP response. I don't really have the freedom to validate just the custom part.

Comment: @GdnMaximus, makes sense, glad you got it working ok now :)

Comment: @Abel I am in a similar situation, how can I get the raw XMl body from the SOAP request to validate just the xml inside the body against xsd file ?

Comment: @Ben that depends on too many factors, you should probably ask a new question and explain your situation in more detail. Typically, you wouldn't need to do this at all, as SOAP is XML and you just validate the whole thing, incl. the body.