# Can't deserialize an HttpResponse message from a REST service using their XSD to generate C# classes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a project where we are consuming a REST api from another company. They have provided an XSD that defines the various objects/elements, along with their attributes, etc.

One is something called QueryResponse which will contain various pieces of data based on what Query REST function I called from the 3rd party.

However, within the returned XML, they wrap it as follows and this is what is returned:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.some.org/soap/envelope/">
     <Body>
          <QueryResponse xmlns="https://erpm.some.org/rpm/xml">
               <PeakLoadSummarySet>
                    <PeakLoadSummary Day="2018-03-10">
                         ... other data associated with a PeakLoadSummary type
                    </PeakLoadSummary>
                    .... PeakLoadSummary can repeat
               ... various other elements they define that can repeat.
               </PeakLoadSummarySet>
          </QueryResponse>
     </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I then extract the XML from the HttpResponse object to deserialize it into a QueryResponse C# POCO that was generated via the XSD command-line utility with Visual Studio using an XSD file provided by the company. However, their XSD does *not* define Body nor Envelope elements. QueryResponse (and there's another one called QueryRequest) are their top level elements and all other items are defined to be wrapped within either a QueryRequest or QueryResponse document.

I attempted to deserialize it as follows in C# in VisualStudio 2019:

```
// HttpResponse has already returned so I extract the content which would be the XML listed above.
string responseString = await msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
MemoryStream stm = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter stw = new StreamWriter(stm);

stw.Write(responseString);
stw.Flush();
stm.Position = 0;

XmlSerialize ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(QueryResponse));
QueryResponse response = ser.Deserialize(stm) as QueryReponse;
```

At the call to Deserialize, it throws this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : there is an error in XML document (1,4).
---- System.InvalidOperationException : <Envelope xmlns='http://schemas.some.org/soap/envelope/'> was not expected.
```

Just to reiterate, their XSD does *not* define the Envelope or Body tags. I'm new to all of this so I'm not sure how to handle this? I know I can generate the code by pasting the XML into Visual Studio using Paste Special but is that the right way to do it? What is the proper way to handle a situation like this when they do not fully specify their XML message format but only a subset of it?

UPDATE: Per a request, here are the classes as they were generated from the XSD:

```
    namespace Schema {
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.8.3928.0")]
        [System.SerializableAttribute()]
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
        [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="https://erpm.some.org/rpm/xml")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="https://erpm.some.org/rpm/xml", IsNullable=false)]
        public partial class QueryResponse {
             private object itemField;
    
             /// <remarks/>
             [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PeakLoadSummarySet", typeof(PeakLoadSummarySetType))]
    
             public object Item {
                 get {
                     return this.itemField;
                 }
                 set {
                     this.itemField = value;
                 }
             }
         }
    
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.8.3928.0")]
        [System.SerializableAttribute()]
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
        [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://erpm.some.org/rpm/xml")]
        public partial class PeakLoadSummarySetType {
            
            private PeakLoadSummaryType[] peakLoadSummaryField;
            
            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PeakLoadSummary")]
            public PeakLoadSummaryType[] PeakLoadSummary {
                get {
                    return this.peakLoadSummaryField;
                }
                set {
                    this.peakLoadSummaryField = value;
                }
            }
        }
    
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.8.3928.0")]
        [System.SerializableAttribute()]
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
        [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]     
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://erpm.some.org/rpm/xml")]
    
        public partial class PeakLoadSummaryType {
            
            private string lSEField;
            
            private string zoneNameField;
            
            private string areaNameField;
    
            /// <remarks/>
            public string LSE {
                get {
                    return this.lSEField;
                }
                set {
                    this.lSEField = value;
                }
            }
            
            /// <remarks/>
            public string ZoneName {
                get {
                    return this.zoneNameField;
                }
                set {
                    this.zoneNameField = value;
                }
            }
            
            /// <remarks/>
            public string AreaName {
                get {
                    return this.areaNameField;
                }
                set {
                    this.areaNameField = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a SOAP envelope. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32590465/create-xsd-for-soap-response.

Comment: Post your c#  classes.  The issue is probably the namespace.

Comment: I've added some to my OP. I didn't want to post the entire thing as it's huge, but I went ahead and posted the main QueryResponse class and.

Comment: BTW. There are other definitions the 3rd party provides (xxxField) which eventually resolve to basic types (strings, ints, etc). Nothing really special there. But what I've posted are the PeakLoadSummarySetType, which is a set of zero or more PeakLoadSetTypes, and the PeakLoadSetType along with all the annotations generated by XSD.EXE via the provided XSD file from the 3rd party provider.

Also, as I've explained in the OP, there are no definitions in their XSD for the Envelope and Body elements. Their API is REST hence, no WSDL is available. Even their documentation states it's REST.

Comment: @bazza, it's definitely not SOAP. I believe they've generated the message structure to mirror SOAP but they have stated it's a REST API. There isn't any WSDL available nor can you query their service to retrieve service definitions.